# Embed Excel sheet in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I wanted to know if there is any way of doing the following in Word 2010. I want my sheet the whole Excel sheet to be able to paste it into Word document.

1. Whenever I modify the data in the Excel sheet I want the changes to appear also in Word document, automatically.
2. Then I also want the ability to modify the contents of the Excel sheet from inside the Word document (for example, I want the ability to change the Excel sheet's cells' values from the pasted/embedded/linked Excel sheet from inside the Word document, and changes also automatically applied to Excel worksheet document).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In Word, just click on the **Insert** tab, then in **Text** group click on **Object**. Then choose and existing file and make sure you click the checkbox that says **Link to File**. Like this:

[image: link to file]

You can then double-click on the object and the original will be updated once you push "Save" in the Excel app that opens up your XLSX. If you have the Excel document open seperately (meaning you didn't double-click on the object in Word) and update a cell, it won't get automatically updated in Word until either 1) you close and re-open Word or 2) press <kbd>F9</kbd>.

This can all be done programmatically as well.

Comment: Hi Otaku, first i select the region from excel sheet and paste it to word document, by using Paste Special -> Paste Link -> Microsoft Excel Worksheet Object. This accomplishes the first part of my question. Then I do what you say, but whenever I double click on the object it opens the linked excel file, which I don't want. Is there any way to update the object contents without opening the excel sheet, i.e. from inside the word document. Thanks!

Comment: @sdfg: I'm trying to understand this - you want the pasted area of the Excel sheet in Word and you want to edit it in Word and have the original Excel sheet that it is linked to also be updated with your edits, *but you don't want Excel to open when you edit it in Word?* If so, the simple answer is *no, because the object displaying is an Excel worksheet, so it must be Excel that edits it.* There is a more complex answer for using code to do this, but it is *a lot* of coding work and still requires a reference to the Excel interop files.